# What is invalid index to scalar variable error in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am quite new to python so please bear with me.

Currently, this is my code

```
import statistics
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/aaronhuang/Documents/Desktop/ffp/exfileCLEAN2.csv", skiprows=[1]) # replace this with wherever the  file is.

start_time = datetime.now()

magnitudes = df['Magnitude '].values
times = df['Time '].values
average = statistics.mean(magnitudes)
sd = statistics.stdev(magnitudes)
below = sd*3


i = 0

while(i < len(df['Magnitude '])):
    if(abs(df['Magnitude '][i]) <=  (average - below)):
        print(df['Time '][i])
        outlier_indicies=(df['Time '][i])


    i += 1



window = 2
num = 1
x = times[outlier_indicies[num]-window:outlier_indicies[num]+window+1]
y = magnitudes[outlier_indicies[num]-window:outlier_indicies[num]+window+1]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('Time (units)')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude (units)')
plt.show()
fig = plt.figure()
```

It outputs this:

```
/Users/aaronhuang/.conda/envs/EXTTEst/bin/python "/Users/aaronhuang/PycharmProjects/EXTTEst/Code sandbox.py"
2456116.494
2456116.535
2456116.576
2456116.624
2456116.673
2456116.714
2456116.799
2456123.527
2456166.634
2456570.526
2456595.515
2457485.722
2457497.93
2457500.674
2457566.874
2457567.877
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aaronhuang/PycharmProjects/EXTTEst/Code sandbox.py", line 38, in <module>
    x = times[outlier_indicies[num]-window:outlier_indicies[num]+window+1]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I solve this error? I would like my code to take the "time" values printed, and graph them to their "magnitude" values. If there are any questions please leave a comment.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell exactly what you are trying to do. But the indexing format you are using should evaluate to something like `times[10:20]`, going from the 10th to the 20th index of `times`. The problem is that (I'm guessing) the numbers you have in there aren't ints, but possibly timestamps?

Maybe you want something like:

```
mask = (times > outlier_indicies[num-window]) & (times < outlier_indicies[num+window+1])
x = times[mask]
y = magnitude[mask]
```

But I'm really just guessing, and obv can't see your data.